# Hide some part of Rectangle shape in CSS

Tags: html, css

[image: I want to achieve]

I want to hide that second rectangular shape and the width should be 100% and responsive.
I am using `position: absolute;` & `right:-10%`.
I also tried `body { max-width:100%; }` but it isn't working.
Could you explain why is this happening and how to fix this?

```css
.container2 {
    position: absolute;
    right: -10%;
    width: 35vmax;
    height: 90vmin;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,hsl(293, 100%, 63%),hsl(264, 100%, 61%));
    border-radius: 50% 50% 0% 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container2"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to have a particular shape to the rectangle or any shape, you should use **clip-path** css property and its very easy, supports most of the latest browsers.

```
clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
```

Please check- [clippy](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) for further reference or help.

I hope this is useful.